# Change image title programatically?

Tags: plugin-development, assets

I save image files from within my plugin through `assets->insertFileByLocalPath()`. 
Unfortunately, i can't give the image title as paramter to the method.

What is the easiest way to change the image title after insert, espacially considering different languages?

**UPDATE**

Ok, i found a solution (moved to the answer), but how do i save values for different languages?

Comment: You should post that as an answer! To select a specific locale you would add `$criteria.locale = "en-us"`. Although you may want to save it without locale first so that it copies the titles to all locales by default; and then retrieve the specific locale using the above, overwrite the title, and save again.

Comment: you're right, i will post an answer. Thanks for the hint with the locale criteria!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how i solved it:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Asset);
$criteria->id = $assetId;
$elements = $criteria->find();
$element[0]->getContent()->title = 'New Title';
craft()->elements->saveElement($element[0]);
```

Comment: Can you check this answer as best answer?